# Is audience network only on native apps?

Tags: facebook, networking, audience

Facebooks audience network for app monetization looks interesting, but is it only for ios and android apps? From the documentation, it doesn't look like there is a Web version (html/js). Is there an equivalent for Web apps?

Answer (score 3):

The Audience Network is currently only available for iOS and Android (and Unity) :)

Comment: Wait, I heard it was on Unity too?

Answer (score 3):

Now it's on mobile web too! You can integrate it like any other Facebook web plugin. For details see:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/mobileweb

Here is what the code would look like:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.Event.subscribe(
          'ad.loaded',
          function(placementId) {
            console.log('Audience Network ad loaded');
          }
        );
        FB.Event.subscribe(
          'ad.error',
          function(errorCode, errorMessage, placementId) {
            console.log('Audience Network error (' + errorCode + ') ' + errorMessage);
          }
        );
        FB.XFBML.parse();
      };
      (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.ad.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5&appId=[APP_ID]";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
  </script>
  <div class="fb-ad" data-format="320x50" data-placementid="[PLACEMENT_ID]" data-testmode="false"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @VinothKrishnan I've updated my answer. Please let me know if it's better now. Thanks!